# Extracted files to /usr, system seems broken now

Tags: linux, debian

I've extracted a tar file with sudo to `/` which contained the following file structure:

[image]

Since then I can't do anything on my server anymore, each command is either permission denied or command not found. Also most of the programs, like Apache or SSH, don't work anymore, although the system is still writing to log files and the virtual machines are still running.

At first I thought I've overwritten the whole `/usr` directory, but actually that's not the case. I've accessed my server via a rescue system and all the files are still there. The permissions seem to be okay too, they all belong to root with `0755` (see second screenshot). The new files have just been extracted into the existing folders, so I don't see how this could have done any harm (I've now deleted them).

[image]

Unfortunately I don't have a backup of `/usr`.

I really don't have an idea what to do now, so it would be great if you could help me. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I think this falls into the category of "don't do that then". "I really don't have an idea what to do now". A reinstallation is probably your best bet. The alternative is to spend a lot of time messing with your system. You'll probably learn quite a lot about Unix-like systems and Debian in particular, but that may not be what you want to be doing... Oh, and avoid screenshots of text. Just paste in the text.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'd really prefer solving this without a reinstallation, just need a hint where to start.

Comment: Well, a simple way would be to look at all those files you have extracted, and then compare those to the permissions of all those files on a non-broken system. If that doesn't work, you'll have to extend things to a larger set of files. There might be better approaches. Another approach is to look at the programs that are not working and try to determine if their permissions looks reasonable. Bear in mind that if the directory permissions as screwed up, it may affect the permissions of the files in them.

Comment: The old files haven't changed as far as I can see. There have been extracted some new ones, but I've already deleted them. The second screenshot I've attached shows that the permissions are intact. Could this have something to do with the file system in general or with mounting?

Comment: The permissions might have changed. Are you sure they haven't? I'm talking specifically about the directory permissions, not so much the file permissions.

Comment: I think `/usr/local/bin` is wrong, at least. I have `drwxrwsr-x   2 root staff  4096 Aug  4  2014 bin` Note the `s`. Also, for `/usr/local`, the group is `staff`, not `root`.

Comment: `permission denied` often means some directory has permissions that are too restrictive. As root, what does `ls -ld / /usr /usr/bin /bin` show?

Comment: It could be that the permissions of `/` have changed. Is there any way I can change them when the concerning disk is mounted as `/mnt`?

Comment: This is a great lesson to learn: probably don't ever manually extract anything to `/usr` and expect things to go okay (except `/usr/local`). *nix has package management; use it. Also, `-1` for a screenshot of terminal output.

Comment: You can do `ls -ld /mnt /mnt/usr /mnt/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this output on your machine. Two things to note:

1. The sticky bit should be set on `/usr/local` and everything below it. From
   the listing in your question, this does not appear to be the case.
2. You need to check that the group is `staff` for everything in
   `/usr/local` and below.

2 is unlikely to be your problem. 1 might well be.

```
root@orwell:/usr/local# ls -lah
total 52K
drwxrwsr-x  11 root staff 4.0K May 26  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4.0K May 30  2014 ..
drwxrwsr-x   2 root staff 4.0K Aug  4  2014 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4.0K May 26  2014 Brother
drwxrwsr-x   2 root staff 4.0K Jul 31  2013 etc
drwxrwsr-x   2 root staff 4.0K Jul 31  2013 games
drwxrwsr-x   2 root staff 4.0K Jul 31  2013 include
drwxrwsr-x   8 root staff 4.0K Dec  5  2013 lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root staff    9 Jul 31  2013 man -> share/man
drwxrwsr-x   2 root staff 4.0K Jul 31  2013 sbin
drwxrwsr-x  11 root staff 4.0K Mar 10  2014 share
drwxrwsr-x 265 root staff  12K Jan 31 07:08 src
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm pretty sure this was part of the problem. Now I only have to restore the permissions of `/`.

Comment: That is very strange... ubuntu doesn't do this and I don't see how it could cause a problem.  The intent seems to be to allow the group "staff" to install programs to /usr/local directly rather than having to su(do).

Comment: @psusi Ubuntu doesn't do what? And what shouldn't cause a problem?

Comment: Set the sticky bit and group ownership to staff on /usr/local -- it's just root.root with no sticky.

Comment: @psusi that is indeed strange. Ubuntu usually follows whatever Debian does, at least in the base system.